# Weighted traffic flow document in AWS is not working as expected?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have the following traffic policy document in AWS

```
Weighted Resource Record Set        Weighted Resource Record Set
----------------------------        ----------------------------
Name: www.example.com               Name: www.example.com
Type: A                             Type: A
Value: 192.0.2.11                   Value: 192.0.2.12
Weight: 1                           Weight: 3
```

And based on the above document 25% of the requests should hit 192.0.2.11 and 75% of the requests should hit 192.0.2.12.

e.g. If I send 4 concurrent requests to www.example.com 3 should hit 192.0.2.12 and 1 should hit 192.0.2.11, but this is not happening.

What I observed is that first few requests will hit only 192.0.2.11 and after some time it hits only 192.0.2.12.

Is this the default beahaviour?

Answer (score 5):

Weighted RRs don't exhibit the behavior you are expecting on a small scale like this.  It is a statistical behavior, not an active load balancing mechanism.

If you were to have 1000 people make 1000 requests at 1000 randomly selected times, you would expect to see *approximately* 250 requests go to one endpoint and 750 requests go to the other.

By the nature of DNS and browser DNS caching behavior preclude you from seeing such a split on small numbers of requests, particularly concurrent requests from a single client.  The more typical outcome is that you will see a 25%/75% split of which server each *viewer* will connect to and often tend to stick to for some period of time.

If you repeat your test 1000 times, you should again see numbers closer to the expecte split.  Longer TTLs on your DNS records will also tend to cause your test results to be less consistent with the weights, if the times between your tests are short.  Shorter DNS TTLs will not be ideal for overall performance, but you might try temporarily setting the TTL to 0 and test again to see what results you get.

Remember, though, that a TTL change doesn't take effect until the time since the TTL change exceeds the old TTL value.  If, for example, the old TTL was 300 seconds, you are not assured of the new TTL having an effect until at least 300 seconds have passed since the time you changed the TTL (plus about 30 seconds for internal Route 53 propagation of the change).